# Why can't I open my Yoosee camera with OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I tried opening my Yoosee camera with OpenCV in Python but got the error "nonmatching transport in server reply". I've posted the same topic, but it violates some of the community rules, so I decide to write this post with a different title.

I've read similar topics, especially the topic with the title "nonmatching transport in server reply" but I've still got no results for me, my code is shown below. Could anyone help me fix it? Besides, I'm using Python 3.11.6 64-bit interpreter from Microsoft store and OpenCV 4.8.0.76. Thank you so much.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os

os.environ["OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS"] = "rtsp_transport; udp"
rtsp = 'rtsp://admin:sinhan123@192.168.1.56:554/onvif1'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(rtsp, cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)

while cap.isOpened:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == False:
        print("Frame is empty")
        break
    else:
        cv2.imshow('VIDEO', frame)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: The `imshow` and `waitKey` should be `if/else` condition block.

Comment: Hi Supra, thank you for your comment but it's not the point here. I've already put the `cv2.waitKey()` method in the `if` block but the result doesn't change. Could you please show me your code recommendation?